# Work around to prevent seeing doc ready javascript changes

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, onload, jquery-deferred

I'm trying to get to the bottom of understanding why I am seeing the following, and how I can work around it:

I have a test page linked below that has an extremely minimal DOM, I have one element on the page that has an initial height value set purely with CSS, on doc ready, a jQuery function fires that assigns a new height value to that element, my issue is that when the page builds, this change is visually noticeable, you can see the element quickly gain its new height value from the jQuery function, my goal is to prevent this, so when the page loads you only ever see the element with its jQuery height value. I thought JavaScript render blocks the page from being built in the browser until all doc ready functions have fired, unless async or deferring has been set, but now I'm assuming I am wrong about that.

**EDIT:**

To clarify, this is just an example, the issue I'm trying to resolve has nothing to do with height specifically, I'm trying to find a work around to the fact there is a visual delay in my jQuery applying CSS on doc ready, and better understand why the delay exists.

[The test page link](http://carbon.cultureinspired.com/test/)

The entire DOM:

```
 <style>
  html {
      background: #eee;
  }
  .box {
      height: 64px;
      width: 50%;
      max-width: 280px;
      max-width: 1280px;
      margin: 64px auto 0 auto;
      position: relative;
      background: #fff;
      box-shadow: 0 0.08em 0.25em 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  }    
</style>

<script type='text/javascript' src='[my path]/js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js?ver=3.1.1'></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery(document).ready(function(){       
      function adjustBox() {
          windowHeight = window.document.documentElement.clientHeight;
          $('.box').css('height', windowHeight * 1/2);
      }   
      adjustBox();     
  });     
</script>

<div class="box"></div>
```

Comment: Why don't you just set the height in the CSS to `50vh`?

Comment: Well I should clarify, this is just a test example, the issue I'm trying to understand is how I can prevent a delay of the javascript taking effect visually on page load.

Comment: You could always animate the element in?? Otherwise CSS is the best way to go, What's your exact problem, usually providing an example can bring answers that aren't actually relevant to your need.

Comment: You can't prevent a delay for javascript to run. You could use a loading overlay and hide that after height is set

Comment: well my issue with this is somewhat cross project, but the height example is fairly close to my real code issue, I've been coding under the assumption the page is rendered in the viewport once doc ready JS has been applied, not after, so it sounds like the solution is proactive and to avoid creating scenarios where the delay creates a problem. For my current project I'll probably just animate a fade in of the whole page as a band-aid fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want that box 50% of the users window height, you can do that with CSS:

```
.box {
    height: 50vh; // vh => view-height
}
```

Your example JavaScript is executed after the DOM has been loaded.
That is why you see `.box` height resizing after the page has loaded.
You can run the JS before the page has fully loaded when you put the `<script>` tag within the `<head>` and don't use the `jQuery.ready()` function.

```
 <head>
    <script>
       // 1
       alert('this runs immediately. even before the document has been parsed');

       // 2
       $(function() {
           alert('this runs when the document has been loaded');
       });

       // 2
       $(document).ready(function(){
            alert('this runs when the document has been loaded');
       });

       // 3
       $(window).load(function(){
            alert('this runs when the document has been loaded AND resources like images has been loaded');
       });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        // 2
        alert('this runs when the document has been loaded');
    </script>
</body>
```

- Commented with `1`: JS cannot manipulate the document here, since it is not loaded yet. You can make redirects or load data from the server etc.
- Commented with `2`: These are basically the same. The document is ready to be manipulated by JS. But that doesn't mean all resources are
  loaded. You cannot get the accurate height of an image.
- Commented with `3`: If you need to get the heights of images you'd want to use `$(window).load`.

Comment: I've edited my question to clarify the issue is related to the delay in the jQuery applying CSS on doc ready, rather than the example I used with height.

Comment: well, you answered the question in the title. "prevent doc ready". So just remove the `jQuery(document).ready`from your JS.

Comment: Well if I remove the doc ready, the code doesn't fire? I'm new to JS/jQuery but I thought it was needed?

Comment: I updated my answer with an example when the JS will be executed

Comment: I tried all combinations you suggested, wrapping it in a function or using doc ready both have the same results visually of showing the height change, the method that takes effect before the document is parsed results in the JS height not being applied, which makes sense, seems like the only solution is to avoid relying on page-load JS that creates FOUSCs, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

You could do something similar to vue/angular/etc... and have a helper attribute that you can apply to "hide" the element until it's been fully processed.

css

```
html {
  background: #eee;
}
[data-cloak] {
  display: none !important;
}
.box {
  height: 64px;
  width: 50%;
  max-width: 280px;
  max-width: 1280px;
  margin: 64px auto 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 0.08em 0.25em 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}
```

js

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){       
  function adjustBox() {
    windowHeight = window.document.documentElement.clientHeight;
    $('.box')
      .removeAttr('data-cloak')
      .css('height', windowHeight * 1/2);
  }   
  adjustBox();     
});
```

[JSFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/cb4v255r/)

Comment: Yet another reason I need to study JS and those kick ass libraries.

Comment: Yeah, FOUSC is tough to fight, but, at least there's some little tricks like this to help tame it.